# ListView with images

Tags: android, listview

I want to make ListView with images. Something like [this](http://www.android10.org/index.php/articlesuserinterface/171-update-custom-listview-images-simply-how-to).
But some of items have text only and don't have images. For those items I want to show text only. 
How can I do that?

Comment: Your link is broken. This causes downvotes

Answer (score 1):

Each item in a list view is a separate view, which can be created as needed. Simply inflate a view from two separate layouts in GetView method of your adapter class.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return new MyViewItem(getImage(), getText(), parent);
}

*****
class MyViewItem extends LinearLayout 
{
    public MyViewItem(ImageClass image, String text, ViewGroup parent) {
        super(parent);

        View.inflate(parent, image==null?R.layout.layout1:R.layout.layout2, this);

        //Now assign correct text and image using this.findViewById() function.
    }
}
```

I leave it to you to define layout1 and layout2 as well as how to handle actual image and text, but this should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I have how many questions. 1. I need to extend SimpleAdapter to override getView method? 2. What is the ImageClass in MyViewItem constructor? Eclipse doesn't recognize it 3. What is the mParent in View.inflate?

Comment: mParent was a typo, I edited the answer, it should be parent. ImageClass is just a name, but the actual class that you are using for images. Or maybe int, if it is a resource ID of the image you will show. Remember that I do not know your code, so I cannot say what is the simplest solution, but I always prefer overriding the class, as it gives you most power, and you will never get stuck with a simple task as today. So, yes, do override the adapter. I use ´BaseAdapter´ as a base class, but probably SimpleAdapter would work.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have 1 view, but just set visiblity to GONE on the image when you dont want the image to be there. As long as you've set up your layout appropriately, the text should pop over to the edge again just fine!

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I have a dummy question. Where should I set visibility?

Comment: `setVisiblity(View.GONE)` on the image view that makes up that row